# how to alt-tab style switch windows

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-manager, lxqt

Using lxqt running mutter on ubuntu 20.04, I cannot forward switch windows, as I would be able to on the gnome-based desktop. I can alt+shift+tab reverse switch, though. When I alt+tab it just switches between current window and the prior window. I have tried  opening the keyboard shortcuts GUI "Global Actions Manager," but that requires script knowledge or so it would appear. Maybe this is the best bet, but I don't know where to start. I have examined the lxqt version of the openbox profile file found in home /.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml and that appears to be written as it should be. I have been tracking my tweaks to the system, including dconf-editor, but there have been so many that I do not think it would help to list them blindly. I suppose I could try reinstalling ubuntu+lxqt but would prefer not.

Comment: Have you looked at the Lubuntu *phabricator* instance details on shortcuts work; problems and then fixes during cosmic->groovy cycles. The settings are multi-layered as LXQt isn't window manager specific (ie. not linked to `openbox`), and if you want clues; that's where I'd look

Comment: I will check out the Lubuntu phabricator instance details on shortcuts work as suggested. It is not something I have looked into yet. Thank you for providing some background on keyboard shortcuts and lxqt not being window manager specific.