# How can I make LAlt+Tab switch windows in Lubuntu 22.04 (LXQt)?

Tags: 22.04, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, lxqt

I've recently upgrade my distribution from Lubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (not reinstalled, upgraded). After my upgrade, the LAlt+Tab key combination no longer switches to the next window; though RAlt + Tab - does.

I looked through the different settings dialogs, and could not find where to change this. I had though about the Shortcuts utility/dialog in particular, but since that one doesn't seem to have even RAlt+Tab, I concluded that's not where I need to make the change.

How do I get LAlt+Tab to work like it used to?

Notes:

- There are other LAlt vs RAlt discrepancies on my system: For example, RAlt+F4 closes windows, but LAlt+F4 doesn't!
- Related, but not identical, to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1259156/193641), where the distro is Lubuntu 20.04 and the user can use LALt+Shift+Tab to switch to the previous windows - which I can't.

Comment: Did you read the Lubuntu 22.04 LTS release notes, and especially the "*Upgrading Lubuntu to 22.04 LTS*" section, as a special instruction is given for those using non-standard `openbox` configurations?  (*which I suspect you are using*). If you used `openbox` configuration changes to accomplish what you used; I suggest you read https://lubuntu.me/jammy-3-released/  (*keyboard shortcuts can be achieved different ways and you didn't specify how you achieved yours*)

Comment: @guiverc: 1. I didn't... I'll read it. 2. I don't know that I used openbox at all. I was using LXQt. Also - I don't know the first thing about OpenBox configuration :-(

Comment: Oh, and - I had a rhetorical mixup and I wrote Shift instead of Tab and vice-versa everywhere. fixed now.

Comment: FYI:  LXQt is the desktop, if you use LXQt alone, the windows will be unable to be resized/moved, they won't have borders or buttons, as the WM does that. LXQt is WM agnostic and doesn't provide those features; Lubuntu includes `openbox` as the window manager; Debian will use `xfwm4` instead.  `openbox` is another part of the software stack of your OS & its what handles windows.